# Realization of $\operatorname{SU}(N) \times \operatorname{SU}(N)$ in chiral perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

Suppose we have $n$ Goldstone bosons which is obtained from the fact that the ground state $\eta$ is invariant under a subgroup $H$ of $G$. Each of these Goldstone bosons will be described by an independent field $\phi_{i}$ which is a smooth real function on Minkowski space $M^{4}$. These fields are collected in an $n$ -component vector $\Psi=\left(\phi_{1}, \ldots, \phi_{n}\right)$, defining the real vector space
$$
M_{1} \equiv\left\{\Psi: M^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \phi_{i}: M^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text { smooth }\right\}
$$
One can show that there is  that there  exists an isomorphic mapping between the quotient  $G / H$  and the Goldstone-boson fields.

Now for QCD in the chiral limit we have $$
G=\mathrm{SU}(N) \times \mathrm{SU}(N)=\{(L, R) \mid L \in \mathrm{SU}(N), R \in \mathrm{SU}(N)\}
$$
and
$$
H=\{(V, V) \mid V \in \mathrm{SU}(N)\} \cong \mathrm{SU}(N)
$$
with $N=2$ for massless $u$ and $d$ quarks and $N=3$ for massless $u, d$, and $s$ quarks.
$$
M_{1} \equiv \begin{cases}\left\{\Phi: M^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid \phi_{i}: M^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text { smooth }\right\} & \text { for } N=2 \\ \left\{\Phi: M^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{8} \mid \phi_{i}: M^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text { smooth }\right\} & \text { for } N=3\end{cases}
$$
Furthermore let $\tilde{\mathscr{H}}(N)$ denote the set of all Hermitian and traceless $N \times N$ matrices,
$$
\tilde{\mathscr{H}}(N) \equiv\left\{A \in \operatorname{gl}(N, \mathbb{C}) \mid A^{\dagger}=A \wedge \operatorname{Tr}(A)=0\right\},
$$
which under addition of matrices defines a real vector space. We define a second set $M_{2} \equiv\left\{\phi: M^{4} \rightarrow \tilde{\mathscr{H}}(N) \mid \phi\right.$ smooth $\}$, where the entries are smooth functions. For $N=2$, the elements of $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are related to each other according to
$$
\phi=\sum_{i=1}^{3} \phi_{i} \tau_{i}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\phi_{3} & \phi_{1}-i \phi_{2} \\
\phi_{1}+i \phi_{2} & -\phi_{3}
\end{array}\right) \equiv\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\pi^{0} & \sqrt{2} \pi^{+} \\
\sqrt{2} \pi^{-} & -\pi^{0}
\end{array}\right)
$$
where the $\tau_{i}$ are the usual Pauli matrices and $\phi_{i}=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr}\left[\tau_{i} \phi\right]$. Analogously for $N=3$
$$
\phi=\sum_{a=1}^{8} \phi_{a} \lambda_{a} \equiv\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\pi^{0}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \eta & \sqrt{2} \pi^{+} & \sqrt{2} K^{+} \\
\sqrt{2} \pi^{-} & -\pi^{0}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \eta & \sqrt{2} K^{0} \\
\sqrt{2} K^{-} & \sqrt{2} \bar{K}^{0} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \eta
\end{array}\right)
$$
with the Gell-Mann matrices $\lambda_{a}$ and $\phi_{a}=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr}\left[\lambda_{a} \phi\right]$. Again, $M_{2}$ forms a real vector space.

Let us finally define
$$
M_{3} \equiv\left\{U: M^{4} \rightarrow \operatorname{SU}(N) \mid U=\exp \left(i \frac{\phi}{F_{0}}\right), \phi \in M_{2}\right\}
$$

Now in order to treat light  mesons as Goldenstone  bosons in this paper
[A Chiral Perturbation Theory Primer](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505265) they  introduce  realization of $\operatorname{SU}(N) \times \operatorname{SU}(N)$ on $M_{3} .$
$$
\varphi: G \times M_{3} \rightarrow M_{3} 
$$

My question is why the realization is made in $M_3$ and not on $M_1$ or $M_2$?

Comment: Why did you edit your original question by replacing it with an unrelated question? You could have made a new question and kept the original!

Comment: That was an old question and I solved it, and since nobody was interested in it  I edit it.  I edit it because if made I knew question I would have to wait 2 days in order to start a bounty.

Comment: Interesting strategy, but someone (like me) would have attempted to answer this question without a bounty.

Comment: After a discussion among the moderators, we’re leaving this question in its current form rather than reverting the edits and removing the accepted answer because there was essentially no activity on the previous version of the question. However, as a rule, using an edit to completely replace a question is frowned upon, and so is bending the rules to be able to promote your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $M_3$ is typically how Goldstone fields enter into the effective Lagrangian in the low energy description. This is what is known as the coset construction. Say we have some field $\phi$ whose VEV spontaneously breaks the symmetry group $G$ down to the subgroup $H$, then we can always make a reparametrisation of the field:

$$\phi(x)=U(x)\tilde{\phi}(x)$$
$$U(x)\equiv\exp\big(i\xi^a(x)x_a\big)$$

Where $x_a$ are the broken generators, and $\xi^a(x)$ are the Goldstone fields. You should think of this particular splitting as a generalization of the canonical example of symmetry breaking, a $U(1)$ $\phi^4$ theory with some potential $V(\phi)=\lambda(|\phi|^2-v^2)^2$, we reparametrize in the following way

$$\phi(x)=(v+\varphi(x))e^{i\omega(x)}$$
where $\omega(x)$ is the Goldstone field and $\tilde{\phi}=v+\varphi(x)$ defines the non-Goldstone modes.

The proof that the $U(x)\tilde{\phi}$ splitting can always be done is a bit technical. It involves first considering whether it's possible for a real and unitary (hence orthogonal) representation of $G$, for which $U(x)\in G$, and then arguing that this implies it works for complex representations. We define $\tilde\phi$ to not contain any Goldstone modes with the constraint

$$\tilde\phi_n(x)(t^a)_{nm}\langle\phi_m\rangle=0$$
Where $\langle\phi_m\rangle$ is the symmetry breaking VEV, and $(t^a)_{nm}$ are the generators of $G$ in the real representation. We must show that there is always a choice of $U(x)$ which allows $\tilde\phi$ to satisfy the above constraint. You can show that the appropriate $U(x)$ is one which maximizes, for a given $\phi(x)$ the following quantity

$$V_{\phi}(g)=\phi_n(x)g_{nm}\langle\phi_m\rangle$$

With $g\in G$. To connect this with some complex representation $\chi(x)$, you can always convert a complex representation to real one with the following identification

$$\phi(x)=\begin{pmatrix} \text{Re}\chi \\ \text{Im}\chi\end{pmatrix}$$

Sometimes it is useful to write the effective action in terms of $\xi^a$, but more often it's easier to see what's going on in terms of $U(x)$. For instance, if the spontaneously broken symmetry is also anomalous, it is much easier to see how these Goldstone fields generate the anomaly in terms of $U(x)$. This is what is known as the Wess-Zumino-Witten term, which can most easily be written as an integral over some $5$ dimensional manifold $B_5$ whose boundary is the $4$d space we're living in  $\partial B_5=M_4$:

$$\sim\int_{B_5}d^5y\epsilon^{ijklm}\text{tr}\Big(U^{-1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial y^i}U^{-1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial y^j}U^{-1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial y^k}U^{-1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial y^l}U^{-1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial y^m}\Big)$$

Writing this in terms of the Goldstone fields $\xi^a$ is not preferred.

Comment: how can I proof that  $\phi(x)=U(x)\tilde{\phi}(x)$ and what is $\tilde{\phi}(x)$?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira $\tilde{\phi}$ is defined to not contain any Goldstone modes. That is, any change in $\tilde{\phi}$ (which leaves the splitting $U\tilde{\phi}$ invariant) moves you out of the symmetry breaking minimum.

Comment: could you give me some references for a good introduction in all of this because I  do not know what Goldstone modes is. I am a self learner

Comment: I have edited to answer your question about the $U(x)\tilde\phi(x)$ splitting.

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I based my answer off of sections 19.6-8 of Steven Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields.

Comment: I will try it but i know Weinberg is very difficult to read

Comment: do all your answers comes from section  19.6-8  of Steven Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127955/discussion-between-fewfew4-and-amilton-moreira).